# A reference for Serre duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like some references for Serre duality for a proper noetherian scheme $X$ (over $\mathbb C$). I know that in this case there exists a dualizing sheaf.
But can theorem 7.6, III, in Harshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" (Duality dor a Projective Scheme) be extended to the case of a proper noetherian Cohen-Macaulay scheme ?
i.e are there natural functorial isomorphisms
$${\rm Ext}^i({\cal F},\omega_X^0)\to H^{n-i}(X,{\cal F})^* \ ?$$
(where $n=\dim(X)$ and $\cal F$ is any coherent sheaf on $X$).

Comment: See Tags [0AU9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AU9) (existence of $\omega_X^\bullet$ on varieties) and [0AWT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWT) (dualising complex on CM lives in one degree).

Comment: I think https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FVZ is a more direct reference for what the OP is asking...

Comment: Also, BTW, @Hephaistos, I think there is a dual sign missing from your displayed line, no?

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn and @ Sándor Kovács. Thank you for the answers. The missing dual sign has been corrected.

Comment: @Sándor Kovács I assume (but it is not clear for me) that Lemma 48.27.5 implies that the isomorphisms are fully functorial, i.e. if we have an exact sequence $\Sigma$ of (quasi-)coherent sheaves then the isomorphisms provide an isomorphism between the long exact sequence of $\Sigma$ in cohomology and the dual of that with the Ext's (in other words the isomorphisms of Lemma 48.27.5 commute with $\delta$-operators).

Comment: Another question that is not treated in Hartshorne's book (except in exercise 7.2) is the local nature of the dualizing sheaf, i.e. if $X$ has one, then for every open subset $U\subset X$, $\omega_{X|U}$ is a dualizing sheaf for $U$.  This would be interesting in the case of a non smooth (or even non reduced non quasi-projective) $X$. In this case there is little hope to describe $\omega_X$ in terms of $\Omega_X$. But it would be nice if it was possible to use an open cover $(U_i)$ of $U$, compute the dualizing sheaves of the $U_i$, and compute $\omega_X$ by gluing the $\omega_{U_i}$.

Comment: @Hephaistos, all of this really comes down to that this is a special case of Grothendieck Duality and if you view it that way, then I think all of your questions are answered. In this lemma in particular, the K is allowed to be a complex. As for the restriction question, it is true in general that a dualizing complex restricts to a dualizing complex. I am sure there is a reference for that on the stacks project.

Answer (score 1):

A basic reference for duality using just sheaves instead of derived categories is the paper:

Kleiman, Steven L.: Relative duality for quasicoherent sheaves. *Compositio Math.* **41** (1980), no. 1, 39–60.

http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1980__41_1_39_0

With this at hand you have a duality theorem for proper algebraic varieties in Lipman's blue book:

Dualizing sheaves, differentials and residues on algebraic varieties. Astérisque No. **117** (1984)

http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AST_1984__117__1_0

See section 4 to begin with.

Finally, to get "higher duality" for a Cohen Macualay variety, this is discussed in  the book

Kunz, Ernst: Residues and duality for projective algebraic varieties. University Lecture Series, **47**. AMS, Providence, RI, 2008.

On page 110 (sec. 12) it is explained how to go form the case $i = 0$ to arbitrary $i \geq 0$. It is stated in the projective case, but the argument carries over the proper case.

Comment: Thank you for these new references.